# How I transfer (ohm*cm)^(-1) units for conductivity into Gaussian units (s^(-1))?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance, units, unit-conversion

I have tables for conductivity of various material in (ohm*cm)^(-1) units. 
 How I transfer those data into Gaussian units (s^(-1))?  Just a coefficient will do....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put a nice revised table into the wikipedia article! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units#Electromagnetic_unit_names

The relevant line is:

$$\frac{\rho_{\text{G}}}{\rho_{\text{SI}}} = 4\pi\epsilon_0^{\text{SI}} = \frac{1 \, \text{s}}{2.998^2 \times 10^{9}  \, \Omega\cdot\text{m}}$$